# msbuild cannot find a file that is actually there

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, file-not-found

for one of my projects, msbuild fails with a file not found error.  however the file is in the source folder both before and after the build attempt.  what am I missing?

Screen Shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be **HandleValuationWarnings** instead of **HandleValuationErrors**

[image]